# Mysql query to insert row not inserting row

Tags: php, mysql

I've dug around here and searched through countless tutorials but it all seems to be in order-
the page I'm creating does everything as it should but its like it skips the mysql code.

first I have a page for a form, create.php:

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/index.css" />
<?php include ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/menu/nav.php');
?>
</head>
<table class="cnrc">
<td>
<?php
$username= $_COOKIE['username'];
$con=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','password','perms')or die("cannot connect");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM permissions WHERE `name`='".$username."'";
$res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
$new_array = $row;
if ($res === false) {
    echo mysqli_error();
}else{
if(mysqli_num_rows($res) == 0){
echo 'It seems you do not have permission to create a town!';
}
elseif (in_array('town.mayor',$new_array,true)){
echo ' <form method="post" action="filecheck.php">
Please name your new town!: <input type="text" name="tname"><br>
<center><input type="submit" name="ctown" value="Create"></center></form> ';
}
}
?>
</td>
</table>
```

then the process of creating a page- filecheck.php:

```
<?php
$tname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['tname']);
$user= mysql_real_escape_string($_COOKIE['username']);
$dir="towns/$tname/";
$path="towns/$tname/$user.php" ;
$path2="towns/$tname/index.php" ;
$path3="towns/$tname/config.ini" ;
$default= "default/user.php" ;
$default2= "default/index.php" ;
$default3= "default/config.ini" ;

if(isset($_POST['ctown'])){

  if(!file_exists($dir)){
        $con=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','password','towns');
        $sql= "INSERT INTO users (username, town, check) VALUES ('".$user."', '".$tname."', 'created')";
        mysqli_query ($con,$sql);
        mkdir ($dir);
  if (!file_exists($path)) {
        copy ($default, $path);
        }
  if (!file_exists($path2)) {
        copy ($default2, $path2);
        }
  if (!file_exists($path3)) {
        copy ($default3, $path3);
    }
    }
    header("Location: editor.php");
}else{
echo 'You have accessed this page incorrectly!';
}
```

Comment: mysql_query() is wrong, look at he manual; query, then resource. You have the arguments backwards

Comment: Learn to use a debugger. Also, your code has security holes (unescaped `$tname` and `$user` composed into the filesystem path) and uses the deprecated `mysql_` functions.

Comment: @Dagon: He is using `mysqli_query` (not `mysql_query`) and the arguments order is fine.

Comment: @ExpertSystem: he's using both `mysqli_` and `mysql_` in different files.

Comment: no for the insert its `mysql_query`

Comment: Oops, true ! Still the error in that case is not the order of the arguments, but the missing 'i' :)

Comment: @ExpertSystem no, he does a mysql_connect beforehand.

Comment: I know. The 'i' is missing there as well.

Comment: thats just an assumption on your part, maybe he misspelt PDO to? :-)

Comment: Why are you using mysql_* and mysqli both ?? ... its terrible .. i am sure its not because you can tell i have used new api(mysqli) in my project according to what ?(price i mean you give me 200$ and in that price i can only use mysqli 50% ).... sorry please use only mysqli or better pdo ... And using mysqli isnt magic bullet your query still ___Vulnerable to sql injection___ you need to escape all request carefully ... so the better will be prepared statements :)

Comment: thanks, i'm used to using mysql and only started using mysqli recently. I know it's all vunerable, just haven't learned how to do anything about it yet- this website is still in testing.

but changing mysql to mysqli didn't solve my problem :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what the issue was, but doing it this way worked:

```
if(isset($_POST['ctown'])){
  if(!file_exists($dir)){
        $con= new mysqli('localhost','root','password','towns');
        if ($con->errno) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $con->error);
        exit();
        }
        $sql = "INSERT INTO `towns`.`users` (`username`, `town`, `check`) VALUES ('".$user."', '".$tname."', 'created')";
        $stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $username_value);
        $username_value = $user;
        if ($result = $stmt->execute()){
        $stmt->free_result();
        }
        else {
        echo "error";
        }
        $con->close();
      mkdir ($dir);
}
```

but even though it works, is this the best way to do it?
note- this is the only section of the code changed, the filecheck.php

Answer (score 0):

With `MySQL_*` you need to select the database after connecting to a resource and you didn't. In `MySQLi_` you do not need that extra step. Why did you start using `MySQL_*` rather than sticking to `MySQLi_` ???

Comment: thanks, used to using mysql and only recently started using mysqli, but its still not inserting the row :S

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you used `mysql_*` here, but it should be `mysqli_*`

`mysqli_connect` takes 4 arguments and `mysql_connect` takes 3 arguments

```
$con=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','weed45654','towns')or die("cannot connect");
mysqli_query ($con,"INSERT INTO users
      (username, town, check)
      VALUES
      ('patey', 'test', 'created')");
```

Comment: thanks, used to using mysql and only recently started using mysqli, but its still not inserting the row :S

I've edited my question with changes I made